# .each function get all except current class

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have following UI for selecting images and it's sequence from drop down.
[image]

now, i have following html code for the sequence drop down.

```
<select id="{{$images_key}}_image_seq_{{$image['id']}}" name="already_image_seq[{{$image['id']}}]" class='other_img_seq image_sequence' onchange="validate_seq(this.value)" style="width: 50%;margin-right: 23%; float: right;">
    <option value="">Select Seq</option>
    @for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++)
        @if($i==$image['seq'])
            <option value="{{$i}}" selected="selected">{{$i}}</option>
        @else 
            <option value="{{$i}}">{{$i}}</option>
        @endif
    @endfor
</select>
```

and i give all of dropdown a same class as **image_sequence**. and for validating not a same sequence for two diffrent images. my javascript is.

```
function validate_seq(value) {
  $(".image_sequence").each(function(){
    if (value==this.value) {
      alert('Sequence already exist');
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

now problem is when validate_seq function gets call it also has it's own vlaue in $(".image_sequence").each(function(). so, i want $(".image_sequence").each(function() without own value. please help me i don't have any idea how to achieve this.

Comment: try `$(this).val()`

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Which is, in this case, the exact same as `this.value`

Comment: true to a degree - I know it's just semantics (js vs jquery) but $(this) could refer to the current jquery object rather than the current object - just a test to try :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

On select element change `onchange="validate_seq(this.value)"  to onchange="validate_seq(this)"`

```
 function validate_seq(ele) {
       $(".image_sequence").not(ele).each(function(){
           // do somthing
          });
        }
```